# How to get first() functionality of MS ACCESS in informix

Tags: database, informix

I have a table called errors and its columns are error_code, dep_index

When I use the below query,

```
select distinct dep_index, error_code from errors;
```

The output is as follows:

```
1000001  09
1000002  10
1000003  09
1000004  10
```

I tried first on dep_index, but unable get desired result as below. I need only the first dep_index for each error_code. Hope I am clear in stating my  issue.

```
1000001  09
1000002  10
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `dep_index` is sequential and increasing then using `min()` to get the lowest value for each error code should do what you want:

`select min(dep_index) as min_dep_index, error_code from errors group by error_code;`